# TCP and KCP product

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics

Q:

> [image]

According to me, the kinetic controlled product(KCP) should be

> [image]

While the Temperature controlled product(TCP) is:

> [image]

What should be the answer to this question because no temperature has been specified. I believe if nothing is given we assume the reaction to be happening at room temperature. So in this case if room temperature is considered, what should be the major product? KCP or TCP.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to reliably answer this question. If no temperature is specified, there's no *scientific* reason why you should assume it's at room temperature. There may be a *pragmatic* reason why you do that, which is to solve your ambiguous homework questions / exam questions correctly; but that's not chemistry, that's exam strategy, and is not relevant for Chem.SE.

Comment: If you were to *only* ask: what is the result at room temperature? then that will possibly be answerable. But in that case, you should edit it to focus only on that, and not go through this detour about how the question doesn't specify a temperature. Then ping me and I can reopen it. By the way, please avoid using nonstandard abbreviations like 'KCP' or 'TCP' without explaining what they are, especially in titles. Assuming that "KCP" stands for kinetically controlled product, your title also contains an extra word: it reads "kinetically controlled product product".

Comment: @orthocresol agreed but for example we commonly say AC Current even though it litreally means alternating current current, it's a convention I believe. But, nevertheless, will try to avoid next time. Also yes I think this question can be closed, it is ambiguous.